# How do I pass an undefined number of methods as parameters to another method

Tags: java, methods

Well I am stuck with a program I am creating, the problem is that I need (?) a method that will able to apply some vehicle settings which they are only applied through methods that are already defined in an API. Here is my code to show the problem more clearly:

```
applySettings(new Vehicle(), setColor(0, 0), setNumberPlate("EA3"));//An undefined number of parameters, the new Vehicle is only for this example, I will use this method in several parts of my code
public void applySettings(Vehicle vehicleId, Vehicle settings/*?*/){

    }
```

(Vehicle is an interface and have many methods some of them are not for settings, I have tried do it with anonymous classes and a thing called lambda or something like that but I couldn't make it work)
As you can see I need to pass a undefined number of methods (that are already defined in an API) to apply the vehicle settings. This I could easily have done with:

```
vehicleCreated.applySettings();
public void applySettings(){
    vehicleId.setNumerPlate("SOME");
    vehicleId.setColor(0, 0);
}
```

But I think it is wrong (I will have to make several methods for different set of settings) because java is an OOPL and I should make things very flexible. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If `Vehicle` is an interface, how does `new Vehicle()` work?

Comment: When you say "I have tried do it with anonymous classes and a thing called lambda or something like that but I couldn't make it work" - perhaps you could post what you tried and describe how it didn't work, and someone might be able to help you with it.

Comment: Instead of passing methods, you could use the Builder pattern and method chaining, to get something like this: `applySettings( new Vehicle(), new VehicleSettings.setColor(0,0).setNumberPlate("EA3").build() )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a functional interface like this:

```
interface VehicleModifier {
     void apply( Vehicle vehicle );
}
```

and implement some classic modifiers with helper methods:

```
static VehicleModifier withColor(int colorX, int colorY) {
    return vehicle -> vehicle.setColor(colorX, colorY);  
}

static VehicleModifier withNumberPlate(String tag) {
    return vehicle -> vehicle.setNumberPlate(tag);  
}
```

Then change your method like this:

```
public void applySettings(Vehicle vehicleId, VehicleModifier... modifiers){
    Stream.of( modifiers ).forEach( modifier -> modifier.apply(vehicleId) );
}
```

You can now call:

```
applySettings(new Vehicle(), withColor(0, 0), withNumberPlate("EA3"));
```

Comment: Very nice. I thought reflection would be the only option to do strictly what the OP posed, and completely forgot about lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the design to use the fluent builder pattern.

```
class VehicleBuilder {
    private String plateNumber;
    // add state properties...

    public VehicleBuilder setPlateNumber(String plateNumber) {
        this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
        return this;
    }

    // add setters for other properties...

    public Vehicle build() {
        return new Vehicle(plateNumber, ...);
    }
}
```

Then construct a Vehicle with:

```
Vehicle v = new VechicleBuilder().setPlateNumber("123").setColor(RED).build();
```

If you *really* needed to pass methods as arguments, it would require reflection and would be *extremely* ugly and difficult to maintain. EDIT: @Prim shows how to do it with lambdas, so reflection isn't needed after all.